# Angular router.navigate won't work from Material Autocomplete

Tags: angular, autocomplete, angular-material, angular-router

I'm in the process of creating an autocomplete control for a search where I can look up products and once someone clicks on one of the products they should navigate to a single product page with that product id in the URL.

My current attempt uses an Angular Material autocomplete (v 7.3.7) and I've modeled this example (https://itnext.io/using-angular-6-material-auto-complete-with-async-data-6d89501c4b79).

While the search part works fine and selects a product when I try to route from the call back method I get an error.  I suspect the issue is that the router object is not visible to the autocomplete possibly because it's in the FormGroup.

Some notes:

First while I would like it eventually route to the product page I've simplified the route to just route to the home page.

I have injected the router into the constructor and I've tried it from a separate test button and it works fine.  I tried the test button both in and out of the FormGroup.

I also tried making the routing object public.

The working code is very close to the tutorial example but I will show what I can here:

The HTML

```html
<form [formGroup]='prodForm'>
  <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
    <input matInput [matAutocomplete]="auto" formControlName='prodInput'>
  </mat-form-field>

  <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete" [displayWith]="navToProd">
    <mat-option *ngIf="isLoading" class="is-loading"><mat-spinner diameter="25"></mat-spinner></mat-option>
    <ng-container *ngIf="!isLoading">
      <mat-option *ngFor="let prod of filteredProds" [value]="prod">
        <img class="example-option-img" [src]="prod.productImage.imagePath" height="35">
        <span>{{ prod.productName }}</span>
        <small> | {{prod.brand.brandName}} | {{prod.category.categoryName}}</small>
      </mat-option>
    </ng-container>
  </mat-autocomplete>

  <div>selected product: {{prodForm.get('prodInput').value | json}}</div>

  <!-- just a test button to see if routing is working outside the control -->
  <button class="btn" (click)="test()">TEST</button>

</form>
```

And the ts

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

import { FormBuilder, FormGroup } from '@angular/forms';
import { switchMap, debounceTime, tap, finalize } from 'rxjs/operators';

import { CatalogService } from '../shared-services/catalog.service';
import { SrfProduct } from '../data-objects/srf-obj-product';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-test-alpha',
  templateUrl: './test-alpha.component.html',
  styleUrls: [
    '../app.component.scss',
    './test-alpha.component.scss'    
  ]
})
export class TestAlphaComponent implements OnInit {

  filteredProds: SrfProduct[] = [];
  prodForm: FormGroup;
  isLoading = false;  

  constructor(
    private router: Router,
    private fb: FormBuilder,
    private catalogService: CatalogService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.prodForm = this.fb.group({
      prodInput: null
    })

    // ===== GET by search term    
    this.prodForm.get('prodInput').valueChanges
      .pipe(
        debounceTime(300),
        tap(() => this.isLoading = true),
          switchMap(value => this.catalogService.getProductsBySearchTerm(value, 0, 10)
          .pipe(
            finalize(() => this.isLoading = false),
          )
        )
      )
      .subscribe(prods => this.filteredProds = prods);

  }

  navToProd(prod: SrfProduct) {
    if (prod) {
      this.router.navigate(['/home']);   // <- this throws the error
      return prod.productName;
    }
  }

  test() {
    this.router.navigate(['/home']);  // <- but this works ok
  }

}
```

In all cases when I route from the `[displayWith]="navToProd"` function, I get a **Cannot read the property navigate' of undefined** error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the reason why you are getting the undefined error is due to **this context**. when you bind`navToProd` as an input like `[displayWith]="navToProd"` **this context** gets lost and it gives undefined error. do some reading about **this context in javascript**

event though you fix the undefined error, still you are using `[displayWith]="navToProd"` in totally the wrong way. `displayWith` is used to map options control value to display value as explained [in docs](https://material.angular.io/components/autocomplete/api#MatAutocomplete) which means it calculates (based on option value) and returns a string to use as display text. it has nothing to do with selection.

if you want to take some action when user chooses an option you should use `optionSelected` event of [MatAutoComplete](https://material.angular.io/components/autocomplete/api#MatAutocomplete)

change your html code as follows

```html
<mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete" (optionSelected)="navToProd($event)">
```

and modify `navToProd` method as follows

```js
  navToProd(event: MatAutocompleteSelectedEvent) {
    const prod = event.option.value;
    if (prod) {
      this.router.navigate(['/home']); // change the url according to prod
    }
  }
```

Comment: I inadvertently found this out as I mocked up a ng-bootstrap typeahead alternate and found for the (selectItem) event handler in the api notes there.  This lead me to go back and look more closely for a similar event in the material api notes.  Regardless thanks for the reply and explanation.